# window.requestAnimationFrame going faster on resize and reload script

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to animate some lines and it's working as expected with window.requestAnimationFrame. But, the lines needs to be repositioned once the user resizes the window. I do that by using a script to re-initialize the Javascript on the page (remove the script tag and append it again). Another approach is to empty the SVG html and repaint the lines.

See this Fiddle for clarification: https://jsfiddle.net/qazc9dnc/

As you can see, the animation is working, but with the following script I'm trying to reload the script that is doing this animation on resizing the window (couldn't get this working on the Fiddle, but it searches for an javascript-tag with the ID relscr):

```
(function (w, d) {
    "use strict";

    Element.prototype.remove = function() {
        this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
    }
    NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
        for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
                this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    var timeout = null,
        scriptEl = document.getElementById('relscr'),
        scriptSrc = scriptEl.src,
        delay = 200;

    w.onresize = function () {
        w.clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = w.setTimeout(function () {
            scriptEl.remove();
            document.getElementById('sectionAnimationSVG').innerHTML = "";
            scriptEl = d.createElement('script');
            scriptEl.type = 'text/javascript';
            scriptEl.src = scriptSrc + '?_=' + (new Date().getTime());
            document.getElementsByTagName('foot')[0].appendChild(scriptEl);
        }, delay);
    };
})(window, document);
```

Well, the animation is going faster each time I resize the window. It is not the random speed variable, but rather the window.requestAnimationFrame function that it triggering double or something, causing the animation to speed up every time I resize.

I'm totally confused and I'd like this problem solved as soon as possible. Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: "*I'm trying to reload the script that is doing this animation on resizing*" - that's the first mistake. You should simply have a function in that script that you can call, and call again on resizing. No need to reload anything to get it reevalated.

Comment: You're not stopping the old animation when starting the new one, so you have two of them going on - which makes it look like you're going at double speed because you have twice the number of steps per time.